# Invoking makeindex for nomencl

Tags: texshop, nomenclature

I have spent many many hours failing to implement nomencl for my PhD thesis. The problem seems to be with invoking makeindex and creating the .nls file

I keep reading that I must invoke makeindex or write a Unix command:

```
makeindex filename.nlo  -s nomencl.ist -o filename.nls
```

But I don't know how to do this. I would be grateful for some instructions i.e. where do I type the command?

I am using TeXShop 2.43.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) -- First you work with the terminal and try whether it works or not.

Answer (score 12):

Save a new file `~/Library/TeXShop/Engines/Nomenclature.engine` with following contents:

```
#!/bin/sh

bfname=$(dirname "$1")/"`basename "$1" .tex`"
makeindex "$bfname".nlo -s nomencl.ist -o "$bfname".nls
```

Make this new file executable using `chmod u+x ~/Library/TeXShop/Engines/Nomenclature.engine` from within a shell or set the executable bit at the file privileges. See, e.g., [WikiHow](http://www.wikihow.com/Change-File-Properties) for more information about how to change file privileges.

Restart TeXShop. Now you should have an entry `Nomenclature` in the drop down menu next to `Typeset`.

To get a nomenclature first run LaTeX, then `Nomenclature`, then LaTeX again.

Comment: I tried making the nomenclature engine but got the following message when I tried to execute: Nomenclature.engine does not have the executable bit set.

Comment: @Peter You have to say, from the Terminal, `chmod a+x ~/Library/TeXShop/Engines/Nomenclature.engine`. Unfortunately, this is not possible from the Finder.

Comment: @egreg: http://www.wikihow.com/Change-File-Properties shows, how you can do it from the Finder. Doesn't this work?

Comment: @Schweinebacke From the Finder it's possible only to set the reading and writing privileges, not the `x` bit (Leopard; no Snow Leopard or Lion machine now).

Comment: @egreg: Interesting!

Comment: Fantastic, thanks folks, that worked perfectly.

Comment: @Peter: You don't need to say thanks. Just upvote (or accept) the answers and great comments.

Answer (score 5):

These are detailed steps to accomplish it:

1) In the mac terminal, go to ~/Library/TeXShop/Engines/ and type:

```
vi Nomenclature.engine
```

2) In the terminal, press the key "i" (for insert) once.

3) From here, copy the following code:

```
#!/bin/sh

bfname=$(dirname "$1")/"`basename "$1" .tex`"
makeindex "$bfname".nlo -s nomencl.ist -o "$bfname".nls
```

4) In the terminal, press "control+clic" and clic on "Paste" menu.

5) In the terminal, press "esc" then type ":wq" and enter (this writes and quits the file).

6) In the terminal, type:

```
sudo chmod a+x Nomenclature.engine
```

7) In the terminal, enter your password.

8) Quit TeXShop (if opened) and start it again.

9) Nomenclature is ready to be executed.

Remember to execute: Latex-Nomenclature-Latex to obtain the expected results.

Comment: Very nice struction to make nomenclature works in Texshop.