# Creating an engine in TexShop for nomenclature

Tags: texshop, nomenclature

I am following [this guide](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37567/invoking-makeindex-for-nomencl) to create an engine-file for TexShop to facilitate the use of the nomenclature package. However, after invoking the engine, it does not happen anything at all - I get no error messages, nor is a file created.

I am using TexShop 3.06 under MacOS Lion and already tried to rule out obvious mistakes (like forgotten return keys etc.). Even if I place echo-commands in the engine file, I get no output.

Are there any ideas on how to obtain a working menu entry?

Comment: Did you place the .engine file at `~/Library/TeXShop/Engines`, and restart TeXShop? Also would be helpful to see the contents of this engine file?

Comment: Did you make the engine file executable? In a Terminal window,  `chmod +x ~/Library/TeXshop/Englines/myengine.engine` (where `myengine.engine` is whatever you named your engine file.)

Comment: @PeterGrill: Sorry for the late reply... I placed the file in the mentioned folder, made it executable, and restarted TexShop. The content of the engine-file is basically the same as in the post mentioned above:
`#!/bin/bash`

`set path= ($path /usr/texbin /usr/local/bin)`
`bfname=$(dirname "$1")/"`basename "$1" .tex`"`
`makeindex "$bfname".nlo -s nomencl.ist -o "$bfname".nls`.

I also experimented with giving the path to makeindex directly, but neither the content from the original post or any changes worked.

Answer (score 3):

This might be a correct version of the `Nomenclature.engine` file:

```
#! /bin/bash
PATH=/usr/texbin:/usr/local/bin:${PATH}
bfname=${1%\.*}
makeindex "$bfname".nlo -s nomencl.ist -o "$bfname".nls
```

In my tests it does the required call.

Answer (score 0):

The code given by @egreg works for me. To answer other questions about where it goes, yes I put mine in `~/Library/TeXShop/Engines`.  If you make a copy of another engine, like `XeTeX.engine` (found in the same folder), rename it `Nomenclature`, and replace the contents with what egreg has provided, then you should be all set.