# (TeXShop) Magic comment in a subfile that runs the main file but including only this subfile

Tags: compiling, editors, include, comments

**Disclaimer:** This question is a bit specific to TeXShop because I have to help somebody who's using this editor I don't know as I don't own a Mac. Nevertheless, it could be helpful to others.

The aim is as follows: a `main.tex` main file `\include`s some subfiles, say `ChapOne.tex` and `ChapTwo.tex`:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{ChapOne.tex}
\chapter{One}
\lipsum[1]
\end{filecontents*}
%
\begin{filecontents*}{ChapTwo.tex}
\chapter{Two}
\lipsum[8-21]
\end{filecontents*}
%
% main.tex file
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\include{ChapOne}
\include{ChapTwo}
\end{document}
```

By running:

1. `pdflatex main`, all the subfiles are included;
2. e.g. `pdflatex "\includeonly{ChapTwo}\input{main}"`, only `ChapTwo.tex` subfile is included.

I'm looking for a way to be able to launch the 2nd run from the corresponding subfile. The (TeXShop) magic comment `% !TEX root = main.tex` is nice but doesn't let me add the `\includeonly` command.

Hence my question: is there another magic comment, like:

```
% !TEX program = pdflatex "\includeonly{ChapTwo}\input{main}"
```

or, better, like:

```
% !TEX program = pdflatex "\includeonly{\currentsubfile}\input{main}"
```

I could use to achieve my goal?

(I know I could achieve a closer goal with the `standalone` class but this would require to add a complete preamble and `document` environment in the subfiles, which I'd like to avoid especially because in the real use case the main and subfiles are not in the same directories and relative paths to some auxiliary files (graphic files among other) wouldn't be the same.)

Comment: Sorry but... when one is using TeXShop or other GUI, one would not want to pass `pdflatex "\blah\blah\blah"` to terminal, right? I would say a GUI-flavor workaround is to create a `control panel.tex` containing `\includeonly` and only include this file in the root.

Comment: @Symbol1 That's the reason I'm looking for a magic comment to put at the beginning of the subfile that lets the user compile as usual (e.g.`command-T` shortcut) but tells 1) the file to be compiled is not the current one but `main.tex` (`% !TEX root = main.tex` magic comment is OK for that), 2) typeset should be run, not with `pdflatex main"`, but with `pdflatex "\includeonly{...}\input{main}"`. About your workaround, no need for an extra file: `\includeonly` could be put in `main.tex`, but I'd like to avoid this as it needs to be changed for each subfile to be individually typeset.

Comment: I said so because I hope that one day we would have a control panel recognizing this file that allows us to *check* something like `<input type="checkbox">`... Well, since nowadays editors are able to recognize `\section` in lines, an independent file is unnecessary in any case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from my comment, you can also

- [create an engine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54792/creating-an-engine-in-texshop-for-nomenclature)
- that [reads the first line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439579/how-to-get-the-first-line-of-a-file-in-a-bash-script)
- and [extracts information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19737675/shell-script-how-to-extract-string-using-regular-expressions).

For example I have an `IncludeOnly.engine` under `~/Library/TeXShop/Engines`:

```
#!/bin/sh
basename="${1%.tex}"
line=$(head -n 1 $1)
re="\% root \= (.+)$"
if [[ $line =~ $re ]];
then pdflatex "\includeonly{$basename}\input{${BASH_REMATCH[1]}}";
else echo "bad subfile";
fi
```

and `225362.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    This is the root file.
    \include{225362-1}
    \include{225362-2}
    \include{225362-3}
\end{document}
```

and `225362-3.tex`

```
% root = 225362
This is the third whatever.
```

magic enough? you may also create some `% includealso = 225362-4` syntax to control everything.