# Executing some code before loading main.tex:is it possible?

Tags: texshop

I'm using `TeXShop` on `macOS`.
The first line of my file `file.tex` is

```
% !TEX root = main.tex
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to execute some code before loading `main.tex`. Something that would look like

```
% !TEX code-before = {\def\test{allo ?}}
```

So that my code would be

```
% !TEX code-before = {\def\test{allo ?}}
% !TEX root = main.tex

blabla
```

The value of the variable `\test` would be used in `main.tex`

Comment: I am not sure I understand the background. If it's just a one-liner then you can type it as code. If it's always the same, longer code you can just `\input` it. On the other hand you talk about "precompile", which sounds more like defining a custom format, which however isn't related to the editor.

Comment: on the commandline you can do `pdflatex '\def\test{allo ?} \input file'`  which you can probably define in your texshop pipeline setup, but I don't think you can do that via a !TeX comment (but I don't know texshop at all)

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I have edited the question to make it clearer.

Comment: There is currently no provision for such a special comment. You can ask the developer to add it (I doubt you'll get it, though).

Comment: Thanks @egreg. I've just sent the developper an email.

Comment: I _think_ https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/225362/texshop-magic-comment-in-a-subfile-that-runs-the-main-file-but-including-only is related, in the sense that you can make TeXShop execute a bash script instead of a LaTeX engine, and you can pass one argument to that script, and you may be able to stuff all the information you need in that one argument and use string processing/regex in bash to get the necessary pieces out.