# Why doesn't MakeIndex work when prompted from TeXshop and TeXstudio?

Tags: indexing, nomencl

Why does it only work if I invoke `makeindex <filename>.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o <filename>.nls` from the terminal/command window?

Comment: Texworkss and texstudio and similar work perfectly fine, `makeindex` is for making an index. On the other hand, package  `nomencl` uses `makeindex`  to generate something different from an index, stuff you have to tell the program (`makeindex`) about. How the hell is your editor, which is a stupid frontend without any common sense, supposed to know that it should tell makeindex to generate a nomenclature list?

Comment: @Johannes_B aha :/ then is there an automatic way I can tell it to run the command by itself without me prompting the terminal each time?

Comment: Change it in the properties of your editor or better, define a new clicky button in the properties. Or just run it in the terminal, that is what i am doing *for every compilation step.

Comment: This question isn't unclear, but it is a duplicate: [Invoking makeindex for nomencl](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/37567)

Comment: And another answer that will also work: [Nomenclature; running makeindex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/216425)